# is there an alternative to for loop?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a function here that will put the innerHTML of each li element to an array

```js
let li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
let array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  array.push(li[i].innerHTML);
}
```

and im wondering if there is any alternative or faster way to do this

i tried using spread operator like this but it only shows the elements and idk how to get the innerHTML of each li

```js
let array = [...li];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Simple map function over the li elements
// Also use const on both variables ('li' and 'array') - as they are not being changed
const li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
const array = [...li].map((e) => e.innerHTML);
```

Comment: `li` is not an array so it has no method `map()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method like this:

```js
let lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
let array = [...lis].map(e => e.innerHTML);
console.log(array);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>SomeThing</li>
  <li>SomeThing</li>
  <li>SomeThing</li>
  <li>SomeThing</li>
</ul>
```